# Hive Table is empty?

Tags: select, hive, tbl-properties

What is the fastest way to check if a table has any records in Hive?

I so far have come across these approaches:

1. Do a `SELECT count(*) FROM <table_name>`, I find this to be slow.
2. Do a `show tblproperties <db.table_name>("numRows");`, I find that these give `-1` if `ANALYZE TABLE` isn't run on table before. Hence would require `ANALYZE TABLE ..` to be run before `SHOW TBLPROPERTIES ..`
3. Do a `SELECT * FROM <table_name> limit 1`. I find this to be the most efficient way.

Are there better ways to do this? 
(I just want to check if Hive table has at least one record)

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I know:

- Hive table is partitioned:

  1) find the location of the table

  ```
  desc formatted <tablename>
  ```

  2) compute the file size in hdfs

  ```
  hdfs dfs -du -h <location of table>
  ```
- Hive is not partitioned:

  1) `show tblproperties <db.table_name>`

  2) find `numRows`

Comment: First approach, I don't find this to be as fast as `SELECT * FROM <table_name> limit 1` as this is a two step process and you have to fire two queries for the result.

Second approach, as mentioned in the question this has down-sides.

Comment: This is what it is. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for alternatives where maybe I could somehow in a single command check if table has any records. Anyhow, thanks for your time.

Comment: We are using Avro and even in case of no data, it writes the header to the file. So option 1 would not be very helpful.